# Allocate Type in Polymoprhic Variable Fortran

Tags: polymorphism, fortran

I am trying to use polymorphism in Fortran, but I have problems allocating the type. I can't figure out how make this work. The Intel compiler threw this error:

```
error #6460: This is not a field name that is defined in the encompassing structure.
analitic%param%a0=2
---------------^
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
program new

implicit none

integer, parameter    :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

type :: potential
  class(*),allocatable                        :: param
endtype

type(potential)          :: analitic
type  :: pa1d_param
  real(dp)     :: a0
  real(dp)     :: b0
end type

allocate(pa1d_param::analitic%param)

analitic%param%a0=2.0_dp     

end program
```

What is wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring `param` as `class(*)`, you are declaring an unlimited polymorphic object. These cannot be referenced in a normal way - they can only be used as actual arguments, pointers or targets in pointer assignment, or as selectors in `select type` statements (16.3.1, Fortran 95/2003 explained, Metcalf and Reid).

In order to do this as you intended, you will have to declare `param` this way: (compiles and produces correct output with ifort 12.0.2.137)

```
program new

 implicit none

 integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

 type pa1d_param
   real(dp) :: a0
   real(dp) :: b0
 end type pa1d_param

 type :: potential
   class(pa1d_param),allocatable :: param
 endtype

 type(potential)          :: analitic

 allocate(analitic%param)

 analitic%param%a0 = 2.0_dp

 write(*,*)analitic%param%a0

end program
```